# Is there any way to turn the caps lock off with USB Rubber Ducky without me touching the computer?

Tags: usb, duckyscript

I am using a USB rubber ducky. I found that if the caps lock on my computer interferes with typing. I want the USB Rubber Ducky to open a youtube URL and it isn't working with caps lock on. Programming my USB to press Caps Lock also doesn't work because it would turn caps lock on if it wasn't turned on previously. **Is there any way to turn the caps lock off without me touching the computer?**

I am not very advanced in this subject so please explain in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're launching YouTube so this won't work for you (maybe).

The way I toggle caps lock is running this in powershell, but if you aren't using powershell then you might have to significantly slow down your script to run this so it might not work. My scripts revolve around powershell script execution so if you go down that path it works great.

```
if ([Console]::CapsLock -eq $true) {$a = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell;$wsh.SendKeys('{CAPSLOCK}')}
```

In ducky script, that looks more like this, provided you have powershell open:

```
STRING if ([Console]::CapsLock -eq $true) {$a = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell;$wsh.SendKeys('{CAPSLOCK}')}
ENTER
```

Then I'd think you could open youtube:

```
STRING start-process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
```

Let me know if you need help with that.